# C conventions - how to use memset on array field of a struct

Tags: c, coding-style, conventions

I wold like to settle an argument about proper usage of memset when zeroing an array field in a struct (language is C).

Let say that we have the following struct:

```
  struct my_struct {
        int a[10]
    }
```

Which of the following implementations are more correct ?

Option 1:

```
void f (struct my_struct * ptr) {
    memset(&ptr->a, 0, sizeof(p->a));
}
```

Option 2:

```
void f (struct my_struct * ptr) {
        memset(ptr->a, 0, sizeof(p->a));
}
```

Notes:

If the field was of a primitive type or **another struct** (such as 'int') option 2 would not work, and if it was a pointer (int *) option 1 would not work.

Please advise,

Comment: Use the correct notation for the type of the element you wish to zero.  You've identified the two notations that are needed; there isn't a single notation that fits all circumstances.  For arrays, you do not use the `&`; for everything else, you do.

Comment: Neither option would work if `a` were a pointer, both would silently give the wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-compound type, you would not use `memset` at all, because direct assignment would be easier and potentially faster. It would also allow for compiler optimizations a function call does not.

For arrays, variant 2 works, because an array is implictily converted to a pointer for **most** operations.

For pointers, note that in variant 2 the *value* of the pointer is used, not the pointer itself, while for an array, a pointer *to the array* is used.

Variant 1 yields the address of the object itself. For a pointer, that is that of the pointer (if this "works" depends on your intention), for an array, it is that of the array - which happens to always be the address of its first element - but the type differs here (irrelevant, as `memset` takes `void *` and internally converts to `char *`).

So: it depends; for an array, I do not see much difference actually, except the address-operator might confuse reads not so familar with operator preceedence (and it is more to type). As a personal opinion: I prefer the simpler syntax, but would not complain about the other.

Note that `memset` with any  other value than `0` does not make much sense actually; it might not even guarantee an array of pointers to be interpreted as *null pointer*.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, option 1 is preferable because the same pattern works for any object, not just arrays:

```
memset(&obj, 0, sizeof obj);
```

You can tell just from this statement that it does not cause a buffer overflow -- i.e. does not access out of bounds.  It's still possible that this doesn't do what was intended (e.g. if `obj` is a pointer and it was intended to set what the pointer was pointing to), but at least the damage is contained.

However if you accidentally use `memset(p, 0, sizeof p)` on a pointer then you may write past the end of the object being pointed to; or if the object is bigger than `sizeof p`, you leave the object in a weird state.